# Select rows between certain (unknown) index

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df that looks like:

```
structure(list(id = c("2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", 
"2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", 
"2023021112", "2023021112"), response = c("1", "Happy", "Sad", 
"Neutral", "Fearful", "2", "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Surprised"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L
), class = "data.frame")
```

For rows between the 1 and the 2 in column 2, I want to add a "-01" to the id (i.e., 2023021112-01). For rows after 2 (in the full dataset, it would be between 2 and 3, eventually n, and n+1), I want to add a "-02" (i.e., 2023021112-02). I then want to delete all rows containing these numeric values in column 2.

How do I say "for rows between n and n+1, add a "-0n" to the id column"? Desired outcome:

```
structure(list(id = c("2023021112-01", "2023021112-01", "2023021112-01", 
"2023021112-01", "2023021112-02", "2023021112-02", "2023021112-02", 
"2023021112-02"), response = c("Happy", "Sad", "Neutral", "Fearful", 
"Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Surprised")), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

suppressWarnings(
df1 %>% 
  mutate(id = paste(id, 
                    sprintf("%02d", cumsum(!is.na(as.numeric(response)))),
                    sep = "-")) %>% 
  filter(is.na(as.numeric(response)))
)

#>              id  response
#> 1 2023021112-01     Happy
#> 2 2023021112-01       Sad
#> 3 2023021112-01   Neutral
#> 4 2023021112-01   Fearful
#> 5 2023021112-02 Disgusted
#> 6 2023021112-02     Happy
#> 7 2023021112-02       Sad
#> 8 2023021112-02 Surprised
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

##### Data:

```
structure(list(id = c("2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", 
                      "2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", 
                      "2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112"), 
               response = c("1", "Happy", "Sad", "Neutral", "Fearful", "2", 
                            "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Surprised"
                      )), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L
                      ), class = "data.frame") -> df1
```

### Explanation:

Here, we are checking for the rows that have a numeric value in column `response` (or rather a value that can be converted to numeric using `as.numeric` function). Then, using `cumsum` whenever the response changes from a string to a number we increase the "identifier".

Let's see the results of each function/step in a separate column to understand this better:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(step1 = as.numeric(response),
         step2 = !is.na(step1),
         step3 = cumsum(step2),
         step4 = sprintf("%02d", step3))

#>            id  response step1 step2 step3 step4
#> 1  2023021112         1     1  TRUE     1    01
#> 2  2023021112     Happy    NA FALSE     1    01
#> 3  2023021112       Sad    NA FALSE     1    01
#> 4  2023021112   Neutral    NA FALSE     1    01
#> 5  2023021112   Fearful    NA FALSE     1    01
#> 72 2023021112         2     2  TRUE     2    02
#> 73 2023021112 Disgusted    NA FALSE     2    02
#> 74 2023021112     Happy    NA FALSE     2    02
#> 75 2023021112       Sad    NA FALSE     2    02
#> 76 2023021112 Surprised    NA FALSE     2    02
```

From here, we just `paste` the `id` and `step4` columns together and filter out the rows based on `!step2` values.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of efficiency, we could `grep` positions of the numbers store it in a vector `w` and `paste` the `rep`eated numbers of `df$response[w]` while keeping it in character format.

```
> diff(w <- grep('^\\d+$', df$response)) |>
+   {\(len) transform(df, 
+                   id=paste0(id, '-', rep(stringi::stri_pad(df$response[w],
+                                                            width=2, pad='0'), 
+                                         each=len)))}() |> 
+   {\(.) .[-w, ]}()
              id  response
2  2023021112-01     Happy
3  2023021112-01       Sad
4  2023021112-01   Neutral
5  2023021112-01   Fearful
73 2023021112-02 Disgusted
74 2023021112-02     Happy
75 2023021112-02       Sad
76 2023021112-02 Surprised
```

(Note that `sprintf('%02s', "1")` for some reason pads `' '` on Linux, thus doesn't really get "ignored" as the documentation states.)