# Select rows between known index and fill a new column with the first value in each index

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a df that looks like:

```
structure(list(id = c("2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", 
"2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021112", 
"2023021112", "2023021112", "2023021113", "2023021113", "2023021113", 
"2023021113", "2023021113", "2023021113", "2023021113", "2023021113", 
"2023021113", "2023021113"), response = c("1", "Happy", "Sad", 
"Neutral", "Fearful", "2", "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Surprised", "2", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Neutral", "Fearful", "1", "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Fearful"
)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 91L), class = "data.frame")
```

For rows from the first number that appears in column 2 until the row before the next number, I want to add a -0n to the id (i.e., 2023021112-01 for the first set-up rows). I then want to delete all rows containing these numeric values in column 2 such that:

```
structure(list(id = c("2023021112-01", "2023021112-01", 
"2023021112-01", "2023021112-01", "2023021112-02", "2023021112-02", "2023021112-02", 
"2023021112-02", "2023021112-02", "2023021113-02", "2023021113-02", "2023021113-02", 
"2023021113-01", "2023021113-01", "2023021113-01", 
"2023021113-01"), response = c("Happy", "Sad", 
"Neutral", "Fearful", "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Surprised", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Neutral", "Fearful", "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Fearful"
)), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 91L), class = "data.frame")
```

In a [previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77412511/select-rows-between-certain-unknown-index), @M-- provided the following partial solution:

```
suppressWarnings(
df1 %>% 
  mutate(id = paste(id, 
                    sprintf("%02d", cumsum(!is.na(as.numeric(response)))),
                    sep = "-")) %>% 
  filter(is.na(as.numeric(response)))
)
```

But due to `cumsum`, it adds "-01", "-02", "-03", "-04", rather than "-01", "-02", "-02", "-01":

```
structure(list(id = c("2023021112-01", "2023021112-01", 
"2023021112-01", "2023021112-01", "2023021112-02", "2023021112-02", "2023021112-02", 
"2023021112-02", "2023021112-03", "2023021113-03", "2023021113-03", "2023021113-03", 
"2023021113-04", "2023021113-04", "2023021113-04", "2023021113-04"), response = c("Happy", "Sad", "Neutral", "Fearful", "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Surprised", "Sad", "Sad", "Neutral", "Fearful", "Disgusted", "Happy", "Sad", "Fearful"
)), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 91L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I swap `cumsum` for something that will provide the desired outcome (shown in code block 2)?

Comment: Oh, okay I thought it was a means of telling the OP to delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

suppressWarnings(
df %>% 
  mutate(id = if_else(is.na(as.numeric(response)), NA, 
                      paste(id, sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(response)), 
                            sep = "-"))) %>% 
  fill(id, .direction ="down") %>% 
  filter(is.na(as.numeric(response))) 
)
#>               id  response
#> 1  2023021112-01     Happy
#> 2  2023021112-01       Sad
#> 3  2023021112-01   Neutral
#> 4  2023021112-01   Fearful
#> 5  2023021112-02 Disgusted
#> 6  2023021112-02     Happy
#> 7  2023021112-02       Sad
#> 8  2023021112-02 Surprised
#> 9  2023021113-02       Sad
#> 10 2023021113-02       Sad
#> 11 2023021113-02   Neutral
#> 12 2023021113-02   Fearful
#> 13 2023021113-01 Disgusted
#> 14 2023021113-01     Happy
#> 15 2023021113-01       Sad
#> 16 2023021113-01   Fearful
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code with just `library(tidyverse)`

```r
df %>% mutate(id2 = ifelse(str_detect(response, '\\d'), 
                           paste0(id,'-0',response), NA)) %>% 
       fill(id2)
```

```r
           id  response           id2
1  2023021112         1 2023021112-01
2  2023021112     Happy 2023021112-01
3  2023021112       Sad 2023021112-01
4  2023021112   Neutral 2023021112-01
5  2023021112   Fearful 2023021112-01
72 2023021112         2 2023021112-02
73 2023021112 Disgusted 2023021112-02
74 2023021112     Happy 2023021112-02
75 2023021112       Sad 2023021112-02
76 2023021112 Surprised 2023021112-02
6  2023021113         2 2023021113-02
7  2023021113       Sad 2023021113-02
8  2023021113       Sad 2023021113-02
9  2023021113   Neutral 2023021113-02
10 2023021113   Fearful 2023021113-02
77 2023021113         1 2023021113-01
78 2023021113 Disgusted 2023021113-01
79 2023021113     Happy 2023021113-01
80 2023021113       Sad 2023021113-01
91 2023021113   Fearful 2023021113-01
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need two libraries for this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)



data %>% 
mutate(id2 = na.locf(if_else(grepl("([0-9]+).*$", response), paste0(id, '-0', gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", response)), NA_character_))) %>%
filter(!grepl("([0-9]+).*$", response))
```

The `grepl` tests to see if the values in `response` are of any number, and if it is this code will `paste0` together `id` and the 0`response`. The `zoo` packages has `na.locf` function which will take the previous value and roll it until the next non-NA value.

```
           id  response           id2
1  2023021112         1 2023021112-01
2  2023021112     Happy 2023021112-01
3  2023021112       Sad 2023021112-01
4  2023021112   Neutral 2023021112-01
5  2023021112   Fearful 2023021112-01
72 2023021112         2 2023021112-02
73 2023021112 Disgusted 2023021112-02
74 2023021112     Happy 2023021112-02
75 2023021112       Sad 2023021112-02
76 2023021112 Surprised 2023021112-02
6  2023021113         2 2023021113-02
7  2023021113       Sad 2023021113-02
8  2023021113       Sad 2023021113-02
9  2023021113   Neutral 2023021113-02
10 2023021113   Fearful 2023021113-02
77 2023021113         1 2023021113-01
78 2023021113 Disgusted 2023021113-01
79 2023021113     Happy 2023021113-01
80 2023021113       Sad 2023021113-01
91 2023021113   Fearful 2023021113-01
```

I left it as `id` and `id2` so you can see the comparison.

Comment: This works well, but it leaves the numbers in the response column, so I have given the check to another answer below

Comment: I updated the code.